# Node.js Jade: Select Option

Tags: javascript, node.js, select, pug

So... I have my select tag with the department item. Each department item has the attribute Department (IT, physic department etc.) It looks like this:

```
select size='5'
  each item in departments
    option= item.Department
```

Now I want to make a connection with my app.js -> When the selected Department changed, the app.js must know the change.

I've tried:

```
select size='5'
  each item in departments
    option: a(href="/printer/#{item.Department}") #{item.Department}
```

but it doesn't work.

I've also tried to make a onchange event.
Like this:

```
select size='5' onchange='selectedDepartmentChanged(this.value);'
  each item in departments
    option= item.Department
```

and this:

```
select size='5'
  each item in departments
    option( onchange='selectedDepartmentChanged(this.value);') #{item.Department}
```

and like this:
    select(id="mySelect") size='5' onchange='selectedDepartmentChanged();'
      each item in departments
        option= item.Department

and this:

```
select size='5'
  each item in departments
    (id="mySelect", onchange='selectedDepartmentChanged();')
```

with the javascript:

```
script(language='JavaScript1.2').
function selectedDepartmentChanged()
{        
    var department = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;  
}
```

What am I missing here?